# blender (2.92 BETA) liquid simulation with viscosity becoming really stretched on one side

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am experimenting with the new "Viscosity" feature in the liquid settings in blender version 2.92  Everything was working the way I wanted it to, until I noticed that during the simulation, the liquid becomes very stretched out on one side, almost as if it is attached to something and can't break away.  It's hard  to explain with words, so I'll show you.(see below image)

[image]

As you can see, it looks like the fluid is trying to hang onto the emitter, causing it to become stretched, and I can't figure out why.

I know that this is an experimental version so maybe this is a bug but I don't feel like it is, any help at all is welcome.

I will share my file with you, but the simulation will only work correctly if you open it using the current BETA version of blender 2.92, which you can download from blender.org if you wish.

[image]

(PS,  if anyone has any questions about some of my current settings that I have, let me know and I can post pictures of them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are too close to a *Domain* border and since you have set collide with all sides of domain it probably stick to it.

When I move it at center it seems to be fine.

[image]

Consider if Domain dimension 28 m is necessary. For realistic result is better to work with real size. To avoid possible issues Apply Scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to all simulation participant to get them all at scale one.

[image]

Comment: thanks for helping me with this.  I feel kind of stupid that the answer was so simple, but it worked, so thanks!